# Java TableModel implementation crashes the program

Tags: java, swing, interface, jtable, tablemodel

In my program I wish to show some data in a `JTable`. I have a class containing the data, so the easiest way to present it in a `JTable` seems to extend my class so that it implements `TableModel` interface and use it as a model for `JTable`. Unfortunately it does not work correctly for me. When the program is about to draw the `JTable`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown at `javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer()`. Why?

```
package bridgecalc;

import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends MyDataClass implements TableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // private Object[][] data; //this is in fact declared in the superclass
    private static final String[] colNames = {"bla", "blabla", "hola", "hej", "egle", "begle", "eciepecie"};
    private HashSet<TableModelListener> listeners;

    public MyTableModel() {
        data = new Object[7][7];
        listeners = new HashSet<TableModelListener>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data[0].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return data[arg0][arg1];
    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return colNames[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (rowIndex == columnIndex)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {        
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        data[columnIndex][rowIndex] = aValue;
    }

}
```

And somewhere in the program:

```
...
JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
this.setViewportView(table);
...
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your problem was the `getColumnClass()` returning null instead of `Object.class`

Use AbstractTableModel as your base class. This way you won't need so many methods. As it is you have just started to handle all the event stuff needed. If you want to do it, copy that code from 'AbstractTableModel` using either the Oracle/Sun source or some other source. Here is some source for some version that will give you and idea of how much code there is to handle the events: [Java Source for AbstractTableModel](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel-source.html)

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModle {

private MyDataClass myData; // holds the cell data

private static final String[] colNames = {"bla", "blabla", "hola", "hej", "egle", "begle", "eciepecie"};

public MyTableModel(MyDataClass val) {
    myData = val;
    myData.data = new Object[7][7];
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return myData.data.length;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return myData.data[0].length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return myData.data[arg0][arg1];
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return colNames[columnIndex];
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (rowIndex == columnIndex)
        return false;
    else return true;
}

@Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        myData.data[columnIndex][rowIndex] = aValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I considered that. I decided to implement `TableModel` instead of extending `AbstractTableModel` intentionally. MyDataClass is a convenient conatainer for my data and it only needs a few aditional methods. Extending `AbstractTableModel` would force me to rewrite much code with no purpouse...

Comment: It's a lot cleaner when the event handling isn't in your code. Try the idea about the data class I put on the first line if you really want to go that way.

Comment: I don't truly handle events in my code, do I? I only manage listeners...

Your sollution works fine, thanks a lot! :)